# How to post file to php server folder

Tags: javascript, php, html

The following code does not work do you know what is wrong? I am trying to send a picture from my computer to the Picture folder on my XAMPP server. The success function works but when I check the Pictures folder there is nothing there.

```
<script>
    function UploadPicture(){

    var file = document.getElementById("pictureinput").files[0];

    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("uploadme",file);


    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/Pictures",
                data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function () {
                    alert("Data Uploaded: ");
                }
            });
    }

    </script>



    <body>
        <div class=container-fluid style="background-color:#6c87cf">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
                <input type="file" accept=".JPEG,.PNG,.JPG" id="pictureinput" name="pictureinput" oninput="ShowPicture();"></div>

                <div class="col"><btn class="btn btn-success" onclick="UploadPicture();">Send Picture</btn></div>
    </div> </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Include details about what isn't working.  Any errors on PHP, any errors in the developer console for JS?

Comment: I get the success function to work but when I check my folder Pictures there is nothing there.

Comment: Where's the PHP part of your script that handles the file upload? Without it we won't be able to help you out. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details.

Comment: @cabrerahector Do I need a PHP script? I thought it would just send it to the folder.

Comment: Yes. The server doesn't know what to do with the data sent via Ajax. You need to tell it what to do with it. You need to use PHP (or any other server-side language, but usually it's PHP) to process it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like cabrerahector said, you need a server-side language to process the temp file and actually move it into a directory. I personally have used https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp to get a minimal grasp of this process and it does help to be a little safe, but if this is just a localhost then your in control.